# Coercing plain HTML to shiny.tags

Tags: r, shiny, htmltools

How do you convert a vector with plain HTML to a nested shiny tag list?

## Rep. Example

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

html_str <- '<div><h1>Headline</h1><p>Text</p></div>'
```

Both `htmltools::as.tags()` and `htmltools::tagList()` don't seem to work. [Although this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/html-to-r-tag-function-converter/5185) shows an example on how one could convert html to shiny.tags, I refuse to believe that there isn't a simpler solution provided by any of the major packages.

## Desired Output

```
result <- tags$div(tags$h1("Headline"), tags$p("Text"))

> class(result)
[1] "shiny.tag"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A solution will require an HTML parser and recursive text generation so the linked solution doesn't seem overly complex to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit either. All the functions like `tags$div()` basically just produce HTML that can be rendered to the page. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the issue you are really trying to solve? You can insert plain HTML into a shiny application.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a Shiny app to perform this task. It uses the JavaScript library `himalaya`. It is available in my package [html2R](https://github.com/stla/html2R). See `?html2R` for usage examples.

[image]